# getattribute for changing textfield value when selection is done in another drop down box

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

My 1st question, hope I make it easy for everyone to understand.

Now I am trying to getattribute of text field whos status is changed when I select a value on a drop down box.
When I select vessels in dropdown box, text field value is changed to (see attachment)
When I select companies in dropdown box, text field value is changed to (see attachment)
So I am clubbing my test scenario with outline which means I am passing different values which will change attributes of text field.

I want to write a if condition so that it checks wat is value selected in drop down and according send keys to text field.enter image description hereenter image description here

Comment: Please add the code that you have tried and what the result was. Also please provide the relevant HTML. You are also referencing attachments that are not attached and images that are not included. If at all possible, please put the text here instead of images because images will eventually expire and this question will be less useful.

Comment: > @JeffC thanks for your reply > <br/><select id="searchDropDown" name="action"><br/><option value="companies">Companies</option><br/><option value="places">Places</option><br/><option value="articles">Articles</option><br/>When I select any one above, With is drop down. My quickSearch Text box changes its property<br/><fieldset> <div id="quickSearchInputPanel"><br/>
<input id="companies" class="searchBox ac_input" type="text" name="companiesSearchTerm" <br/><input id="places" class="searchBox ac_input" type="text" name="placesSearchTerm". I am writing Scenario Outline so can pass diff values

Comment: Given I am logged in on ABC.com
    And I select "<quickSearch>" in search Drop Down box
    And I enter "<searchText>" in quick search box
    When I click "Go" button
    Then I Should be redirected to "<vesselText>" overview page. Examples:
      | quickSearch | searchText   |
      | Places          | New York    |
      | Companies   | ABRS Limited | I select Places from drop down and field and quick search text field changes its properties, how do i get want is current property of quickTextfield

Comment: Please add these comments to the question so others will be more likely to see it and it can be properly formatted.